# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_code'

Tags: python, azure

He estado intentando hacer uso de uno de los códigos que tiene Microsoft Learn para sus servicios cognitivos, pero tengo un problema con una librería. Las librerías que usan para un ejercicio de análisis de imagen son:

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision import ComputerVisionClient

from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

from python_code import vision

import os
```

Instalé las librerías de Azure tal cual lo mencionan en Microsoft Learn, pero al momento de correr el código de prueba me sale el siguiente error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "d:\Python\P1.py", line 6,
> in 
> from python_code import vision ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_code'

Entiendo que es porque hace falta, pero no he conseguido información sobre como instalar ese modulo, he intentado con pip install python_code, Python_Code, Vision y otras más, pero no doy con el correcto, alguien sabe qué podría hacer?
Estoy utilizando Python 3.7.7

Comment: Ese módulo parece un módulo propio del curso. Consulta la documentación del curso o contacta con algún tutor del mismo para ver cómo se instala (Puedes verlo en el siguiente repositorio: https://github.com/MicrosoftLearning/AI-900ES-Microsoft-Azure-AI-Fundamentals)

Answer (score 0):

debes usar

```
pip install azure-cognitiveservices-vision-face
```